# How do I know whether to use a std::array or std::vector for data parsed from a file, and how can I improve allocation performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, stdvector, stdarray

I have an input file, and it has 3D vector data line by line. I want to read this vector data and store it in the program. I thought I have two options:

I can count the number of lines, and I can create a fixed array
OR
I can insert my 'vector data' to `std::vector` object with `push_back`

My question is which one is the fastest way to do that task?

If there is another way to do that please explain me.

Comment: Both for array and `std::array` you need to know the number of lines at compile time, so your only choice in what you suggested is `std::vector` (you could also benchmark `std::list` and `std::forward_list`, but I'd say start with a vector). EDIT: if you meant counting the lines manually and use a `std::array`, then that would indeed work. I'd say it could be a bit faster but you should benchmark it to know.

Comment: How big is the file?  Worry about correctness first, speed second.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a question of speed as much as it is about the nature of your inputs, since that's really what the type of collection that is appropriate depends on.

If your input file has a fixed number of lines, where that number is known at compile-time, and all such input files will have that same number of lines, then you can use a container that supports compile-time-known sizes, such as `std::array`, and throw an exception or use some other error handling mechanism if an unexpected number of lines is provided by the file.

If the number of lines is not the same for all such input files of this type, you will have to use a container that supports variable size at runtime (non-compile-time-known size), such as `std::vector`. In such cases, if you want to avoid unnecessary performance costs of reallocations when increasing the capacity of the underlying buffer of the container, then you can consider changing the format of your input file such that it begins by describing the number of lines of data (now you're basically giving your input file schema a *header* section to describe the nature of the following data). Then, when reading the file, you can read the header, and use the value it contains to  call [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). Of course, you will also need to adjust the part of your program that writes those files to keep the header info in sync with the data. And if you use such a header and don't trust that the input file will have been written correctly (which is actually a reasonable thing to think), you should also not assume that the amount of data lines matches the number reported in the header, and throw an exception or use your project's method of error signalling when appropriate.

Performance outside of allocation performance as controlled by your program is not really in your control- for example, disk performance will for the most part depend on the type of disk, the type of filesystem, and behaviours of your operating system in reading from files. What I believe you could still do is tweak the buffer size of the standard input stream's underlying buffering (see [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::rdbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf)), but the nature of whether that can cause improvements may end up depending on those aforementioned factors. Do however take a look at [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) and see if it may be suitable for use in your program.